# Update table without using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have data like this

[alt text http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/8518/data.png](http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/8518/data.png)

I want to update minP, maxP and agvP columns on the basis of Id. My desired result is;

[alt text http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/2029/updatedu.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/2029/updatedu.png)

Please help.

Comment: Good question, clearly asked.  I also like the pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
update mt
set minp = a.minp,
maxp = a.maxp,
avgp = a.avgp
from mytable mt
join
(select id, min(price) as minp, max(price) as maxp, avg(price) as avgp
from mytable group by id) a on a.id = mt.id
```